# Windows 7 XP Mode - Is it possible to have multiple XP Mode Virtual PCs?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode

Windows 7's XP Mode virtual PC supports some features that aren't 'stock' with an XP Virtual PC such as a different start-up dialog, no Shutdown button, etc.  Possibly the most significant is that applications installed within the XP Mode VM appear within the Windows 7 start-menu.

I have a need for multiple XP Mode VM's--is it possible to have 2 or more XP Mode VM's, or to otherwise enable these extra integration features in an XP Virtual PC?

Comment: Just remember that unless you own the extra licences, this will not be legal! Windows 7 only includes *ONE* licence to run Windows XP Mode

Comment: What about the applications installed under this virtual mode. Can you enable shortcuts to run applications within multiple VMs?

Comment: If something is in the start menu its already a shortcut.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you simply copy a clean XP virtual machine (the ones you can download from the Microsoft website), you can rename it and have multiple XP VMs that way.

At least it worked for me, let me know if it doesn't

[Here's an overview of the required steps:](http://www.sevenforums.com/virtualization/19604-how-copy-virtual-xp-machine.html)

> Every virtual hard drive (vhd) created
>   with Virtual PC consists of three
>   files if it is turned off, or of four
>   files if it is hibernated or running.
>   The file extensions for these files
>   are:
>
> - .vhd = Virtual Machine virtual hard drive image
> - .vmc = Virtual Machine settings file
> - .vsv = Virtual Machine saved state file
> - .vmcx = Virtual Machine description and registration settings
>
> First three files are located in
>   `C:\Users\Your_Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows
>   Virtual PC\Virtual Machines`, the last
>   one in `C:\Users\Your_Username\Virtual
>   Machines`.
>
> The two latter files are created
>   automatically; to make a copy of a
>   Virtual Machine we only need .vhd and
>   .vmc files. In this example we call
>   the original virtual drive Windows XP
>   Mode, and the copy we create Windows
>   XP Mode- Copy. You can name all your
>   virtual drives as you like, as long as
>   you remember to modify the settings
>   file as described here.
>
> Copying Virtual XP or any other
>   virtual hard disk created with Virtual
>   PC is very easy and fast. Here's what
>   you have to do:
>
> - Turn off your Virtual XP, do not hibernate it
> - Open Folder Options, choose Show hidden files, folders and drives.
>     Uncheck Hide extensions for known file
>     types
>
> [image]
>
> - Goto `C:\Users\Your_Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Virtual PC\Virtual Machines`
> - Copy `Windows XP Mode.vhd` and `Windows XP Mode.vmc` files. To be sure you copy
>     the right files you can open Folder
>     Options and uncheck "Hide extensions
>     for known file types" and click OK
> - Paste files to the same folder. Windows adds word `Copy` to both
>     filenames, so now you have two new
>     files: `Windows XP Mode - Copy.vhd` and
>     `Windows XP Mode - Copy.vmc`
> - Open `Windows XP Mode - Copy.vmc` with Notepad. It is a xml-file, so you can
>     edit it normally with Notepad
> - Find the following string containing virtual drives name: `<drive_type type="integer">1</drive_type>`
>
> [image]
>
> - Under the `<drive_type...>` change the vhd-file name to `Windows XP Mode -
>     Copy.vhd` both in `<absolute
>     type="string">` and `<relative
>     type="string">`
> - Find the following place under `<ethernet_adapter>` containing
>     MAC-adress for Virtual XP's ethernet
>     adapter: `<ethernet_card_address type="bytes">xxxxxxxxxxxx</ethernet_card_address>`, where xxxxxxxxxxxx is a hexadecimal string representing the MAC-address.
> - To allow two copies of Virtual XP to connect to network simultaneously , we
>     have to change the MAC-adress of the
>     ethernet adapter to avoid MAC-adress
>     conflict. Address is given in hex, 0-9
>     and A-F. It is usually enough to change one
>     digit to make it unique again.
> - Save and close the file
> - Open Folder Options and choose Don't show hidden files, folders or drives.
>     Check Hide extensions for known file
>     types and click OK.
> - Goto `C:\Users\Your_Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Virtual PC\Virtual Machines` again
> - Double click `Windows XP Mode - Copy.vmc` file so that the `Windows XP Mode - Copy.vmcx` is automatically generated in the `C:\Users\Your_Username\Virtual Machines` folder with the correct settings.
>
> That's it. Now you can run two Virtual
>   XP's simultaneously.
>
> [image]

If both VMs...

- .. still have the same MAC-address
  or
- .. both get the same IP-address from Virtual PC's DHCP server

Then read on:

> - Verify if a (Windows) network adapter (NIC) setting isn't forcing the same MAC address for both VMs. Because that setting overrules what is specified in the VM configuration file.
> - You can find this setting in the properties of the network adapter. Right click the network adapter -> Properties -> Configure... -> [Tab] Advanced -> Network Address.
> - Make sure either both VMs are set to `Not Present`, or specify a different MAC addresses for each VM.

Comment: I made use of this method (copy and rename) to have 1 XP mode with IE6 and another with IE7

Comment: Just remember that unless you own the extra licences, this will not be legal! Windows 7 only includes *ONE* licence to run Windows XP Mode

Comment: It's on the same computer, so what's the problem? Unless you start "abusing" it to share your VMs, I don't see an issue here.

Comment: It's still a technical violation (as I understand it, though IANAL) of the license agreement.

Comment: I doubt Microsoft considers this illegal, as they are hosting http://xpmore.codeplex.com/ since 2010 (CodePlex belongs to Microsoft)

Answer (score 16):

For what it's worth, at this time, if you don't want the manual hassle you can just use [XP-More](http://xpmore.codeplex.com), a free tool that can duplicate Windows Virtual PCs such as XP Mode, but don't forget to disable the Windows XP firewall.

Answer (score 3):

You can have as many as you wish, but programs started from Windows 7 menu (XP mode) will work inside of same virtual machine. All other instances can be used just as standard virtual machines.

Answer (score 3):

An easier and (AFAIK) more legal approach is to use Virtual PC's differencing functionality as described [here](http://weblog.200ok.com.au/2010/08/browser-testing-with-windows-7-xp-mode.html).

Answer (score 1):

I found out by experimenting that the configuration number needs to be incremented in the vmc file, (using Win 7 Ultimate + Windows XP Mode dnld 7 - OCT - 2010)

Tried XPMORE (which is great, but needs the above fix to work!)

Comment: Can you describe the steps to take? Where is the `.vmc` file located? How do you edit it? More information helps make this answer better for future visitors. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a video of the process on youtube. Looks to be a little simpler than what Ivo posted and it worked just fine for me. It involves locating the read-only vhd file of XP already on the machine and creating a new vm using the "Differencing" type under advanced options. This will use the specified read-only vhd but it will store changes/customizations in a separate vhd. Pretty much all point and click...

The vid is here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cmqWVTczvs